# Display only some items of a LinqDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview binded with a LinqDataSource in the aspx code. I need to display only some items stored in the database. How can I do it from c#?

In aspx:

```
<asp:GridView 
        ID="GridViewItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="LinqDataSourceItems" />
```

In c#??

Comment: Cant you write query to return whatever you want?

Answer (score 0):

Since we're stabbing in the dark here, how about a WhereParameter in your LinqDataSource?

```
<asp:LinqDataSource runat="server" ID="LinqDataSourceItems" ContextTypeName="CamillasDataContext" TableName="TableFoo" OrderBy="CreatedDateDescending" Where="ThingId == @ThingId">
     <WhereParameters>
           <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="id" Name="ThingId" Type="Int32" />
     </WhereParameters>
 </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

In addition to QueryString parameters, you also have Parameters for: Route, Session, Cookie, Form, Profile and more.